# clearRect left and top not clearing

Tags: javascript

I want to create a simple object moving in canvas. with keyboard controller. but clearRect not work as expect. and also if can give example and multiple keydown detection like press arrow top with right will increase x and y by 1

> window.requestAnimationFrame

```
    "use strict";

const canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

var width = 1366;
var height = 544;

canvas.width = width;
canvas.height = height;
canvas.style.backgroundColor = 'black';

var x = 0;
var y = 0;
ctx.fillStyle = "#FF0000";
ctx.fillRect(x,y,15,15);

window.addEventListener('keydown', function(event){
    var o = event.keyCode;
    switch (o) {
        case 37:
            x -= 1;
            ctx.fillRect(x, y, 15, 15);
            ctx.clearRect(x-1, y, 1, 15);
            break;
        case 38:
            y -= 1;
            ctx.fillRect(x, y, 15, 15);
            ctx.clearRect(x, y-1, 15, 1);
            break;
        case 39:
            x += 1;
            ctx.fillRect(x, y, 15, 15);
            ctx.clearRect(x-1, y, 1, 15);
            break;
        case 40:
            y += 1;
            ctx.fillRect(x, y, 15, 15);
            ctx.clearRect(x, y-1, 15, 1);
            break;
        default:
    }
});

document.body.appendChild(canvas);
```

thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have added a line to clear the whole canvas and then fillRect. Try this method.

```
const canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

var width = 1366;
var height = 544;

canvas.width = width;
canvas.height = height;
canvas.style.backgroundColor = 'black';

var x = 0;
var y = 0;
ctx.fillStyle = "#FF0000";
ctx.fillRect(x,y,15,15);

window.addEventListener('keydown', function(event){
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    var o = event.keyCode;
    switch (o) {
        case 37:
            x -= 1;
            ctx.fillRect(x, y, 15, 15);
            break;
        case 38:
            y -= 1;
            ctx.fillRect(x, y, 15, 15);
            break;
        case 39:
            x += 1;
            ctx.fillRect(x, y, 15, 15);

            break;
        case 40:
            y += 1;
            ctx.fillRect(x, y, 15, 15);

            break;
        default:
    }
});

document.body.appendChild(canvas);
```

Comment: It's work. i don't realize clearRect can be use like that.

Comment: do you know how to detect multiple key? when press D + W. it will decrease y and increase x by 1?

Comment: Use onkeydown (or onkeyup), not onkeypress for that and the corresponding key code for D and W.

Comment: example please in switch expression. `case():`

Comment: i currently in progress create a mmorpg game. that can do many thing. like jump, many slot skill, walk 8 direction. and click direction. i need that fire event. to complete the interactive.